# Query subform, not working when used through navigation form

Tags: forms, ms-access-2013, subforms

I'll keep this as clear as I can:

My database has two tables:

```
Clients
Contacts
```

They have a relationship: For each client (Which is a company, for your understanding) there can be any number of related contacts.

The database has three relevant forms:

```
SearchFrm
NavigationFrm
ContactsSubFrm
```

`SearchFrm` is a form that reads from the `Clients` table, and has a combo box that, according to chosen record (name), displays all it's other fields in their respective text boxes.

Inside `SearchFrm`, `ContactsSubFrm` appears as a datasheet subform, that displays all contacts related to the chosen record in the form, (using a query of `Contacts.[Workplace ID])=[Forms]![SearchFrm]![ID]`

`NavigationFrm` serves as a means of navigation between forms. For now, it's only for `SearchFrm`, but more will come.

And now, the problem: The query that `ContactsSubFrm` runs doesn't work inside `NavigationFrm`, when run, I get an input window for `[Forms]![SearchFrm]![ID]` every time it's suppose to run. This only happens inside navigation.

I'm pretty sure this is because the `SearchFrm` form itself is closed, and has a problem working through a navigation form, but I can't think of a solution.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the answer to the same question, so I thought I'd put my solution here in case anyone else comes looking for it...

As stated above, you have to reference the field within your form within your navigation form in your query (as opposed to just the field within your originally created form.)

The best way to do this is:

1. Open your navigation form.
2. Open any other form.
3. Access the expression builder from the other form.
4. Find the field *in your navigation form* that you need to reference. Mine looked something like this:
   Forms![NavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].Form![Field]
5. Copy and paste into your query

Answer (score 0):

Since your form moved location (now inside a navigation form), You could try to modify your query from: `[Forms]![SearchFrm]![ID]` to: `[Forms]![NavigationFrm]![SearchFrm]![ID]`

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that, but I get the same result (Now with request for input on `[Forms]![NavigationFrm]![SearchFrm]![ID]`

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with my project right now... If I get to fix it I share it here and maybe it will also work for you.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a DLookup. Inside the navigation form it didn't work. So I changed and instead of: `[Forms]![SearchFrm]![ID] ` I just wrote `[ID]` and Access got it right. However, in your case you establish the parameter from the query itself, so I don't know whether it could work.

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting idea. Sadly, while Access did get it right in 'SearchFrm', and when I went to the navigation form it didn't prompt me to enter an input, the problem became that the datasheet doesn't update in the navigation form, it remains empty.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this by changing the reference in the query itself to

```
[forms]![frmNavigationForm]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![ID]
```